# Ember-DS queryRecord returns TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Tags: javascript, ember.js, browser, ember-data

I'm trying to do a `queryRecord` search inside of my `model` function and I seem to be hitting an error:

`TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object`

My `model()` looks like the following:

```
model() {
  return this.store.queryRecord('model', { property: 'value' })
    .then(doc => console.log(doc)) // This doesn't even invoke
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this error is due to the `XHR` or `REST API` returning `null` or `undefined` as the response instead of an empty `Object` or `Array`.

```
> GET /model?query=x
< null
```

should be

```
> GET /model?query=x
< {}
```